# Change Float and equation numbering format?

Tags: numbering, lyx

I'm using LyX and book document class, can I change float and equation numbering format to become [Chapter number].[Float number] instead of the default [Chapter number].[Section Number].[Float number]?

For better explanation please see this :

What I want :

```
Chapter 1
Chapter title
   Float 1.1
1.1 Section 1
   Float 1.2
   Float 1.3
 1.1.1 Subsection 1.1.1
   Float 1.4
 1.1.2 Subsection 1.1.2
1.2 Section 2
   Float 1.5
 1.2.1 Subsection 1.2.1
   Float 1.6
```

Default :

```
Chapter 1
Chapter title
   Float 1.0.1
1.1 Section 1
   Float 1.1.1
   Float 1.1.2
 1.1.1 Subsection 1.1.1
   Float 1.1.3
 1.1.2 Subsection 1.1.2
1.2 Section 2
   Float 1.2.1
 1.2.1 Subsection 1.2.1
   Float 1.2.2
```

Can I apply this to equation too?

Comment: if you're using `amsmath`, you can say `\numberwithin{xxx}{section}` where "xxx" can be `figure`, `table` or `equation`.

Comment: I have found the solution, thanks for commenting.

Comment: Do you want to have separate counters for figures and tables or count them together?

Comment: Separate counter, but is it possible to count them together? Sometimes I need that too.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Document > Setting > Modules, and remove Number equation/figures by section.